# How can I access a sponsored job post´s costs and clicks through the LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

This is an informative question, not a coding problem.
I´m building a recruiting integration for the company I work in. We want to be able to calculate our costs per hire and costs per application. To do so I´d like to access - through the API - the costs of our sponsored job postings on LinkedIn and the clicks they´ve gotten (basically the same info that is available for ad campaigns).
Nevertheless, I haven´t been able to find any information on available api endpoints for this task and I´m feeling genuinely lost.
Is this possible at all? If yes, does someone know about any API endpoints or resources I could take a look at?

I´ve pretty much read all of the publicly available LinkedIn API documentation but I´ve also read that there are some endpoints that are only available for partnered devs. I don´t have any more info than that. Sorry if this isn´t specific enough.